# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"hot"' can't be used to index type 'NodeModule'

Tags: typescript

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"hot"' can't be used to index type 'NodeModule'.
Property 'hot' does not exist on type 'NodeModule'.ts(7053)

Comment: Please include the problematic code and any errors you encountered. With this little information, it's very unlikely you'll get an answer, let alone a helpful one.

Answer (score 0):

The hot property on node modules is not standard one.
You need to install the required type definitions. Run the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env
```

After running above command, add into your tsconfig.app.json the following type:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["webpack-env"]
  },
 ...
}
```